# Dynamically Create Macros (Specifically UDFs) from VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, metaprogramming

I don't know if I have been using the correct search terms or not when searching for this functionality, but I'm curious, is it possible to dynamically generate macros in excel-vba? If so, what are the possible methods?

Is metaprogramming supported in excel-vba?

Comment: Yes eg http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956104/add-user-defined-function-to-visual-studio-excel-add-in

Comment: @Sorceri Forgive my ignorance regarding VBA/C#, on your response, what's the context of the provided C# code? Could that code be executed from within the VBA project?

Comment: @jab it is a pretty straight forward conversion, see my answer

Comment: @Sorceri Very straightforward, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example I provided converted to VBA.  You will need to include a reference to Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility and enable access to the VBA project module in the trust center settings.

```
Sub CreateMacro()
Dim vbComp As VBComponent
Dim functionText As String

Set vbComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)

functionText = "Function MyTest()" & vbCrLf
functionText = functionText + "MsgBox " & Chr(34) & "Hello World" & Chr(34) & vbCrLf
functionText = functionText + "End Function"

vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromString functionText

End Sub
```